# How do I correctly return a sequence of classes with the query expression?

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

I am new to F# and having trouble translating some C# code.
I have a class similar to this:

```
type car () =
    member val Model = "" with get,set
    member val Year = "" with get,set
```

I have this query expression that pulls car data from the database:

```
query{
    for row in db do
    select // <-- what is the correct syntax to create a sequence of new car 
           //    classes here
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's a lot easier if you don't translate 1:1 or at least if you add an constructor.

For example using a primary-constructor this should work:

```
type Car (model, year) =
   member __.Model with get() = model
   member __.Year with get() = year

query {
   for row in db do
   select (Car (row.Model, row.Year))
}
```

now of course I don't know how the rows in your `db` looks like and this will give you immutable data - but for what I see it should be fine

---

I just realised that this might be a problem (just as in C#) as the ctor probably cannot be translated into a SQL-statement - you can still try but I guess you really need to do

```
query {
   for row in db do
   select 
} |> Seq.map (fun row -> Car (row.Model, row.Year))
```

instead (sorry - cannot really try right now)